# Code that concatenates new lines does not execute else statement

Tags: python, if-statement

```
with open('small_plate_data.txt', 'r') as f:

    for line in f.read().split("\n"):
        p = 1
        op = ''
        cntr = 2
        num_plate = 0
        if line.startswith("Plate"):
            with open('Plate' + str(cntr) + '.txt', 'w+') as opf:
                opf.write("Plate"+ str(num_plate) + "Data")
                opf.write(op)
                opf.close
                op = ''
                cntr += 1
                p += 1
                num_plate +=1
        else:
            op = op + '\n' + line
f.close()
```

The code above opens a txt file and reads it line by line. It concatenates every line together unless a line begins with 'plate', where it then takes whatever has been concatenated and then saves it to a file. The problem is that it doesn't concatenate...and never executes the else statement.

Comment: FWIW `f.read().split("\n")` is just `f.readlines()`

Comment: And `opf.close` should be `opf.close()` (but you don't even need it since you are using `with`)

Comment: @DeepSpace … or simply `f`.

Comment: For the concatenation part it won't work since you reset the `op` variable at each iteration of the loop. You should put the `op = ''` outside the for loop.

Comment: In the else-clause you assign to `op`, but the next iteration of the loop sets it to an empty string (`op = ''`). This means `op` will *always* be an empty string when you write it.  It's not that the else-clause never gets run, it's that it makes no difference when it does.

Comment: For performance, you should either maintain a `list` of component `str`s (that are either `'\n'.join`-ed at the last moment or just dumped with `writelines`) rather than performing repeated concatenation, or, if you want to be lazy and will never run anywhere but on the CPython reference interpreter, at least change `op = op + '\n' + line` to `op += '\n' + line` so the CPython optimization for repeated concatenation (that often allows it to realloc in-place rather than allocate new memory, copy, and free old memory over and over) isn't broken.

Comment: For the "correct" solution, you could change each `op = ''` to `op = []`, change `op = op + '\n' + line` to `op += ('\n', line)`, and lastly change `opf.write(op)` to `opf.writelines(op)`. Also note, using mode `'w+'` is pointless (you never read the file), so just use `'w'` for the mode.

Comment: @DeepSpace: They're slightly different (and `f.readlines()` is an abomination that should have been killed in Python 3); the OP's code removes all the newlines, and possibly leaves an empty string at the end (when the file ends in a newline); `readlines` keeps 'em. Really, the correct solution is usually `for line in f: line = line.rstrip("\n")  # rest of code here`, or if you really hate two-liners, `for line in map(operator.methodcaller('rstrip', '\n'), f):`, both of which avoid pre-slurping the file into memory (requiring memory proportionate to file size) by lazily iterating the input.

Comment: You made an assertion that it "never executes the else statement". Did you actually check this? If you had checked it, you would see that it was indeed executed and that fact would have helped you debug this problem.